# Messagebox.Show doesnt work because its a method group? C#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm very new to C# and I was just writing a very basic code could anyone help me out? I am trying to simply show a variable (inputted by the user via the textbox) show up in the message box... Thanks :)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name1 = textBox1.Text;

    MessageBox.Show = (name1);
    textBox1.Text = ("");
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name1 = textBox1.Text;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses for `textBox1.Text = "";`.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), not a property, so you need to call it using this syntax

```
MessageBox.Show(name1);
```

Related, `textBox1.Text` is a string property so you need to change that syntax to

```
textBox1.Text = "my string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click event could be rewritten as this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(textbox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

and this section of code doesn't actually have any significance. name1 is only in scope inside the text changed event handler, and you do nothing with it.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name1 = textBox1.Text;
}
```